# I'm very new to Sencha and need to get data from a SQL stored procedure. Which is the best way to do this?

Tags: sql, extjs

I'm very new to Sencha and need to get data from a SQL stored procedure. Which is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an API endpoint to get the Store procedure's returned value.
2. If the returned value is going to be a list, you can use [ExtJs Store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html) to store the list of values and bind them to any table or so.
3. If the returned value is going to be a single set or a single value, you can use [View Model or element's specific model](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) to store the data obtained. You need to use [ExtJs Ajax Request](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request) to fetch the data from the API Endpoint.
4. Bind the data from Store/Model to your UI.